# How do I pass a value from a form for validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am creating a **form** for a direct debit with **Ruby on Rails**.

I have the form set up and I have set some basic validation to make sure that all fields are filled out.

Next I want to set some validation to check than an IBAN (International Bank Account Number) number is a valid IBAN.

This involves several steps manipulating a string, changing it to a number and doing some maths, all of which I have written a method for.

My problem is that I don't seem to be able to pass the IBAN into the method to do the validation.

My validation:

```
class DirectDebit < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :address, :amount, :bank_branch, :bic, :date_for_payment, :email, :iban, :name, :name_of_account, :phone

validates :address, :bank_branch, :bic, :date_for_payment, :email, :name, :name_of_account, :phone, presence: true

validates :amount, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}

validate :iban 

def iban

    ## Converts all letters in 'number' to uppercase and removes any spaces and anything else that isn't a letter, number or underscore
    iban = iban.upcase.scan(/\w/).join

    ## removes any underscores as ".scan(/\w/)" above reads in letters digits and underscores.
    iban = iban.gsub(/_/, '')

    ## Calculates the length of 'number'
    iban_length = iban.length

    ## Saves the first two letters in 'number' as 'country'
    country = iban.scan(/\A../).join

    ## Checks if the length is correct for the country
    length_correct_for_country = true

    case country
        when "IE"
            if iban_length == 22
                length_correct_for_country = true
            else
                length_correct_for_country = false      
            end
        when "AL"
            if iban_length == 28
                length_correct_for_country = true
            else
                length_correct_for_country = false      
            end
        ...
        when "GB"
            if iban_length == 22
                length_correct_for_country = true
            else
                length_correct_for_country = false      
            end
        when "VG"
            if iban_length == 24
                length_correct_for_country = true
            else
                length_correct_for_country = false      
            end
    end

    ## Identifies what the first 4 characters are, and removes them from the rest of the number
    first_four_characters = iban.slice!(0..3)

    ## Adds the first four characters to the end of the rest
    reordered_number = iban + first_four_characters

    ## Set up an array and have each character in the reordered number read into it, changing it to the appropriate number if it is a letter.
    letters_removed = []
    reordered_number.scan(/./) do |character|
        case character
        when "A"
            letters_removed << 10
        ...
        when "9"
            letters_removed <<9
        end
    end

    ## Change the array to a String and then to a number
    letters_removed = letters_removed.join.to_i

    ## Check to see if it gives a remainder of one when divided by 97
    remainder = letters_removed % 97

    ## Output that it is a valid number if the remainder when it is divided by 97 is 1 and if it is the correct length for the country.
    if remainder == 1 && length_correct_for_country

    else
        remainder = remainder.to_s
        errors.add(:iban, " That is not a valid IBAN. The IBAN that is being supplied is: " + special)
    end

end

end
```

Comment: In first line try `iban = self.iban.upcase.scan(/\w/).join`. Also if you are not sure what is the value use debugger or just put 

`Rails.logger.info "*"*50; Rails.logger.info [:iban_after_smth, iban].inspect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, iban is already a method since it is a database column. So, you'll want to do something like:

```
validate :valid_iban?

def valid_iban?
  ## all of your current validation iban goes here
end
```

If you'd like to be able to validate both the model's iban, and potentially other ibans:

app/models/validates_iban.rb

```
class ValidatesIban
  def self.valid?(iban)
    ## all your validation goes here
  end
end
```

and in your model:

```
validate :valid_iban?

def valid_iban?
  unless ValidatesIban.valid?(iban)
    self.errors(:iban, "is not valid")
  end
end
```

The good side of the ValidatesIban approach: you can reuse elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, the ValidatesIban approach worked once I had monkeyed with it a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this one is covered pretty well, but I'd like to add some more options:

1. You can use gem 'iban-tools', https://github.com/iulianu/iban-tools
2. Also, for (SEPA) direct debit forms/protocol, try this sepa_king gem which also validates BIC and Creditor Identifier (you can see that internally for IBAN it also uses iban-tools, https://github.com/salesking/sepa_king/blob/master/lib/sepa_king/validator.rb)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :your_method


  def your_method
    #your stuff should return true or false        
  end

end
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: That's a basic version of what I have.

Comment: Done, there are two long repetitive sections that I have cut out the middle of and replaced with lines that just read ...

Comment: Returning true or false isn't the problem, nothing is getting passed in to be tested, as a result I'm effectively getting false everytime, unless I hard code an IBAN that will validate to true.

Comment: change your method name to something else.